# JList doesn't show Content 50% of the Time

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I stumpled upon a Problem with Java wich seems very strange so I didn't found anything in the internet.

I want to make a little program wich just searchs for specific files to delete them. (Not at this point yet) Right now, the Program just searchs for all files in the dir and in the subdirectories. It works but sometimes (about 50/50) the JList, I use to show the files, does not show anything. (This is the problem I have) I dont change any Files, nothing changes to the .jar, it just does not show the elements sometimes.

I also checked if the array is maybe empty, there are elements in it, even when the List does not show them. It would be greate if you know a solution to this. Thank you.

Here is the Code: (Just so you know, I did not wrote the function GetAllFiles by my own)

Variables:

```java
JList output;
JScrollPane outputScrollPanel;
DefaultListModel outputContent;
String[] files;
int fileIndex;
File source;
```

Constructor:

```java
    add(output = new JList());

    outputContent = new DefaultListModel();
    output.setModel(outputContent);

    add(outputScrollPanel = new JScrollPane(output));
    outputScrollPanel.setBounds(20, 20, getWidth() - 50, getHeight() - 40);

    files = new String[0];
    fileIndex = 0;

    SearchFiles();
```

The SearchFiles-function together with the GetAllFiles (I did my best, not taking redundant Names ;) )

```java
private void SearchFiles() {
    source = new File("");
    GetAllFiles(source);
    for(int i = 0; i < fileIndex; i++) {
        outputContent.addElement(files[i]);
    }
}

private void GetAllFiles(File dir) {
    File[] fileList = dir.getAbsoluteFile().listFiles();        
    if (fileList != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
            if (fileList[i].isDirectory()) {
                GetAllFiles(fileList[i]);
            } else {
                if(fileIndex%100 == 0) {
                    IncreaseFileListSize();   
                }
                // i am so proud of this one: (it just adds the relative path + file name to the files-array
                files[fileIndex] = fileList[i].toString().substring(source.getAbsolutePath().toString().length()+1);
                fileIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT. (That sounds like the problem). 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Also, in Java the naming conventions are a bit different. Your methods shouldn't start with an uppercase.

Comment: What do you mean with EDT?
I will upload a .jar in a minute. ;)

btw. I have plenty of time getting used to naming conventions,...

Comment: EDT=Event Dispatch Thread. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Comment: I see, so starting the functions within the constructor is a problem, am I right?

Comment: Haha, putting the method into a button seems to work. Are there any other solutions wich would work without anoter "click"? 

Thanks for the quick response sofar. :)

Comment: You can push `Runnable`s from other threads to the event queue using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

Comment: so how would this look like?

Comment: Whenever in another thread and needing to do GUI work: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { /* do the stuff */ } } );`